# How to use parameters from another list in a condition query

Tags: c#, linq

I've got code and i need carsID from carsList in my query. I want to use IN or Contains but I can't do this. Can I combine it all in one query?

```
    var carsList = db.model.Where(c => c.MarkID == myMarkID).ToListAsync(); 
var query = await from engine in db.engines
            join manufacturer in db.manufacturers on engine.id equals manufacturer.engineID
            where engine.forCarID == ??
            select new { engine.parameters, manufacturer.name }
```

Comment: You can use `Contains` in LINQ. `where carsList.Select(c => c.carsID).Contains(engine.forCarID)`. But unless you have a particular reason to do so, prematurely using `ToListAsync` is inefficient - leave it off, and hopefully your LINQ provider will convert to SQL for the whole query.

Comment: how to write it? Because I have two different style for the query.

Comment: That doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the queries and use `Contains`:

```
var carIDsList = db.model.Where(c => c.MarkID == myMarkID).Select(c => c.carID);
var query = await from engine in db.engines
            join manufacturer in db.manufacturers on engine.id equals manufacturer.engineID
            where carIDsList.Contains(engine.forCarID)
            select new { engine.parameters, manufacturer.name }
```